# SpriteKit crash on [self removeAllActions];

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit, ios9

Just moved into the open iOS 9 Beta (version 3) and my app is now crashing on this line:

```
[self removeAllActions]; // where "self" is an SKNode
```

Edit: After digging a little further I found the problem occurs when removeAllActions is inside a completion handler:

```
[self runAction: someSKAction completion:^{
    [self removeAllActions]; // this will cause the crash
}];
```

The error in the console states:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
```

Is anyone else having this sort of problem?

Edit: I was not having this problem with any versions of iOS7 or iOS8. I submitted a bug report to Apple, report #21788047

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208079/spritekit-crashing-with-stdout-of-range-vector-issue

Comment: @sangony thanks for the link; I'll look into that. My actions are not related to loading my textures or any form of + (SKAction *)animateWithTextures:(NSArray *)textures. Like suggested in the other thread I will set up logs around my arrays and look for nil objects

Comment: Same error on iOs 12 and Swift here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this issue and it happens because there is concurrent access to the `actions` array of a `SKNode`.

I got rid of it by using a `semaphore`. It's not the ideal solution but at least it stops crashing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved with iOS 9 Beta 4. After updating, I ran a few tests and everything seems to be working smoothly.